# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION runtime error when attempting to calculate

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

So, I'm making a simple app to calculate simple values inputted by the user and some values that are already in the app, but I keep getting this runtime error every time I try to calculate the result:

Here is the code:

```
    var mycalc:Double!

    for(var i = 0; i<name.count; i++){
        if name[i] == typeFood{
            yieldOutput == percent[i]
            mycalc=percent[i] / 100.0
        }
    }

    yieldOutput.text = String (format:"%.2f", percent )
    var portionSize = typeDesired.text.toInt()! / typeOriginal.text.toInt()!
    var myint:Int=typeAmount.text.toInt()!
    var myres:Double=Double(myint)*(mycalc)*Double(portionSize)
    amountOutput.text =  String (format:"%.2f", myres)
    self.typeDesired.resignFirstResponder()
```

I get the error in this line:

```
  var myres:Double=Double(myint)*(mycalc)*Double(portionSize)
```

error:
2015-04-19 14:43:11.385 YieldMart[1124:26108] Can't find keyplane that supports type 4 for keyboard iPhone-PortraitChoco-NumberPad; using 2705787216_PortraitChoco_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

i think mycalc returns nil for some reason?

Comment: what is the data type of myCalc and portionSize? can you share the data type of variable declarations?

Comment: Check the `==` in the line `yieldOutput == percent[i]`. Shouldn't it be `=` only?

Comment: Do you see any console output?

Comment: No I want yieldOutput to equal percent[i]

Comment: Do you see the error on a device or in the simulator?